# Mocking generic methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics, moq

Assume I have some interface with a generic method and no parameters:

```
public interface Interface {
   void Method<T>();
}
```

Now I wish to implement the mock for this class (I'm using `Moq`) and I wish to mock this method for some concrete type - let's say I'm mocking `Method<String>()` calls.

```
mock = new Mock<Interface>();
mock.Setup(x => x.Method ????).Returns(String("abc"));
```

The idea of `????` should be clear - this lambda expression should handle the case when `T` in the `Method<T>` is actually a `String`.

**Is there any way I can achieve the wanted behavior?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply:

```
mock.Setup(x => x.Method<string>()).Returns("abc");
```

Also make sure that your method actually returns something as currently the return type is defined as `void`:

```
public interface Interface
{
    string Method<T>();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<Interface>();
        mock.Setup(x => x.Method<string>()).Returns("abc");

        Console.WriteLine(mock.Object.Method<string>()); // prints abc
        Console.WriteLine(mock.Object.Method<int>()); // prints nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `string Method<T>` be `T Method<T>`?

Comment: @Secret Agent Man, no, it shouldn't. At least there's nothing that obliges it to do so. It was just an example I took. A method can return whatever you want. If you want you can replace the `string` return type with `T`, the example will still work.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used Moq myself, but I'd expect:

```
mock.Setup(x => x.Method<string>());
```

(Note that your sample method has a void return type, so it shouldn't be returning anything...

Comment: In which case setup is unnecessary as the mock is created in loose mode.